# Can't get Flutter app on real device to make http request on Node.j server running locally

Tags: android, node.js, flutter, port

I have my Node server running locally on `127.0.0.1:3000` and with my Flutter app running on Chrome `localhost:5000` I can send http requests to url `localhost:3000` and they all respond.
I'm now trying running it on a real Android device connected via usb and with the same url I get `error: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 45614` error.
Now, why port 45614 (from the error) gets used if the url localhost port is 3000?

I got my ip4 address and used that in my Flutter app url as was suggested in various posts here on SO, tried with and without port as `static String dbUrl = '192.168.43.105';` or `static String dbUrl = '192.168.43.105:3000';` but requests are not hitting the server.
I tried setting adb to the  Node.js server port 3000 with `adb tcpip 3000`and that restarted the ads server listening on port 3000 but still requests won't hit my Node.js server..

Running `adb devices` command gets me `5203e95d43cd93a7 device` which is the connected Android tablet, and with `adb forward --list` I get `5203e95d43cd93a7 tcp:56393 tcp:41547` but I can't find out which port is which and how to use it..
Sorry for the probably messy question but as you can see I'm quite lost here and after reading various posts here on the subject I only got me more confused..
Any help would be very much appreciated.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to get your pc ip address, for example your ip address is 192.168.1.1 then add port which u are using in your backend like 8000 or 8080. so now your url will be like http://192.169.1.1:8000/. and make sure your server/backend is running and your device and laptop is connected with same network.

It will work!

Comment: Hi, indeed I'm doing this already, as you can see in my question I have my server running on `127.0.0.1:3000` and my ip4 adrress

Comment: is your phone is connected with same network?

Comment: the tablet is connected via usb cable to run the flutter app

Comment: the thing i am trying to ask is your laptop and table is connected with same internet? i was also facing the same problem i resolve it by connecting the same internet on both device and running server successfully.

Comment: Yes they are connected to the same wifi network.

Comment: I'm not sure why but when connecting tablet and computer to the home wifi I get the connection refused error,  so just to try I used the hotspot from my mobile and connected both the tablet and the computer to it and it worked .. I guess I have some issue with my home router as I experience intermittent connection at times.. Thank you very much again. Cheers.

Comment: Glad it helps u!

Answer (score 0):

first try adding `http://`, so it will be something like this

```
http://192.168.43.105:3000
```

if that didn't work try allowing firewall on port 3000.

###### note: the following solution worked for .netcore server so it might not work with nodejs

try changing your server url to the following:

```
http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

Comment: adding `http://`didn't work, still getting the refused connection error, and I have no firewall turned on. Any idea?

Comment: what os are you using ? linux, mac or widnows ?

Comment: I'm on mac. I did add the ip to listen to in my server but it wasn't necessary..